# <select> element - Using `ngRepeat` to generate select options

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

#### Bind data to each row and also change the bound data based on condition

I need bind data to every row in angular & also edit the same bound data based on conditions.

```
<select id="subject" name="subject"  ng-model="subjectName">
 <option ng-repeat="s in subjects" value="{{s.Id}"
         ng-init="subjectName=physics">{{s.Name}}</option>
 </select>
```

I am binding list of subjects to every week, so, it will look like

```
Daily                              <<Drop down with list of subjects>>

1/1/2015                        English, Mathematics, Chemistry
1/2/2015                        English, Mathematics, Chemistry
1/3/2015                        English, Mathematics, Chemistry
1/4/2015                        English, Mathematics, Chemistry
1/5/2015                        English, Mathematics, Chemistry
```

In another screen, user assigns to only few subjects for particular date range.

```
Start date:1/1/2015
End date: 1/3/2015
Only assigned subject: English
```

So, the expected result is

```
Daily                              <<Drop down with list of subjects>>

1/1/2015                        English
1/2/2015                        English
1/3/2015                        English
1/4/2015                        English, Mathematics, Chemistry
1/5/2015                        English, Mathematics, Chemistry
```

I want items to be removed from the drop down for each row(based on each date entry).

How do i bind this scenario in angular, i am beginner in angular, so need some help.

Comment: Start by reading - [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference - Using `ngRepeat` to generate select options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this below code, also check this sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EeVEVLSlGOJyotN6YZFQ) for you example scenario.

**Template:**

```
<select ng-model="item.subject" ng-options="sub.id as sub.name for sub in SubjectList">
   <option value="">Select Subject</option>
</select>
```

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.SubjectList = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'English'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mathematics'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Chemistry'
  }];
```

Comment: Thanks, i want items to be removed from the dropdown for each row(based on each date entry).